# createAudioSource is undefined with old webRTC library (early 2014) on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webrtc, libjingle

I am developing an Android app with visual and audio communication to a node.js server. I am using webRTC. My problem is that the sound does not work from the browser (computer) to the app (android device). I want to add the *factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints)* to the *AudioTrack*. But eclipse does not let me use that method. It says:
"The method createAudioSource(MediaConstraints) is undefined for the type PeerConnectionFactory"

I tried to use a newer webRTC library (libjingle_peerconnection.jar) from October 2015, then this method is valid but I get other errors related to the videostream, so that I cannot use it.

Is there a possibility to get a library from between, somewhere end 2014? I think this should resolve my problem. Or do you have another solution?

Thanks in advance

Vektor

Comment: Since webrtc is still a work in progress, I would recommend you to always use the latest (stable) revision.

Comment: I don't want to change everything in my code. I just want the function createAudioSource() to work.

Comment: Well it doesn't exist yet in your revision, you need a higher revision. Changing to another revision means changing some code. You are better off keeping up with the changes (by updating your lib every few revisions) than to use an old revision now with the chance to have to redo major parts of your code just to get a new feature.